# Receiving error when using mix ecto.create

Tags: sql-server, elixir, ecto, tds

This is my configuration for the database:

```
config :hello, Hello.Repo,
  username: "postgres",
  password: "admin",
  hostname: "localhost",
  database: "hello_dev_postgres",
  show_sensitive_data_on_connection_error: true,
  pool_size: 10

config :hello, Hello.MRepo,
  adapter: Tds.Ecto,
  username: "sa",
  password: "server",
  hostname: "localhost",
  instance: "SERVER",
  port: 1433,
  database: "hello_dev_mssql",
  show_sensitive_data_on_connection_error: true,
  pool_size: 10
```

And this is my two repo:

```
defmodule Hello.MRepo do
  use Ecto.Repo,
    otp_app: :hello,
    adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Tds
end

defmodule Hello.Repo do
  use Ecto.Repo,
    otp_app: :hello,
    adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres
end
```

When I run mix ecto.create, I get this error:

> 16:37:43.867 [error] GenServer #PID<0.309.0> terminating
> ** (Tds.Error) tcp connect: econnrefused
> (db_connection 2.4.2) lib/db_connection/connection.ex:100: DBConnection.Connection.connect/2
> (connection 1.1.0) lib/connection.ex:622: Connection.enter_connect/5
> (stdlib 3.17) proc_lib.erl:226: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
> Last message: nil
> State: Tds.Protocol
> (Mix) The database for Hello.MRepo couldn't be created: killed

Comment: So what's in your `config/config.exs` file? It sounds like it's configured to connect to a port that's different than what the SQL Server instance is listening on, or that there's a network/software firewall product blocking the connection.

Comment: This is my config!config:exs

config :hello,
  ecto_repos: [Hello.Repo, Hello.MRepo]

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled TCP in your database configuration file?

There is a similar [post](https://elixirforum.com/t/tds-error-tcp-connect-econnrefused/44419/3?u=ryanzidago) on the elixirforum where someone had the same problem as you and enabling TCP in one of the configuration file helped them.

Comment: thanks a lot, the problem was solved with the activation of port 1434 and port 1433 and with the restart of all the processes